# JavaFX screen resolution scaling

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, screen-resolution

I have been searching for a method to do this, but I only found [This question without answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453173/javafx-scale-elements-to-screen-resolution).

I am developing in a 1366x768 laptop, I use JavaFX to create a GUI (I am sorry, but I can't post the code, it's basically an AnchorPane containing a couple GridPanes, which contain more GridPanes, which contain Labels, TextFields and a couple Charts).

The problem comes when I load the project on another resolution (1920x1080 or 1600x900).

I am using `stage.setMaximized(true);`, but this only Scales the background, the stage itself, so all the elements and containers (Panels, Labels, TextFields.....) remain the same size as with the 1366x768 resolution, making the GUI "not fit" at resolutions that are not exactly 1366x768.

I hope I explained my problem well enough, my english is far from perfect.

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to make elements scale with stage resolution?

(I need the software to be maximised or full screen in every monitor, so making a fixed resolution (1366x768, for example) doesn't seem like a good solution).

Thank you all.

**Update:**

I just created a little example. It's a 2x1 GridPane inside the default JavaFX AnchorPane, I added two example Buttons to the grid pane.

```
<AnchorPane minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" >
<children>
    <GridPane prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="400.0">
        <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
        <children>
            <Button fx:id="example1" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Example 2" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="CENTER" />
            <Button fx:id="example2" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Example 2" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.valignment="CENTER" />
        </children>
    </GridPane>
</children>
```

This code looks nice in a 400x300 screen (Too little, I know, it's just an example), when I scale it to 1366x768 (Not real full screen, just `stage.setMaximized(true);`), the GridPane does not scale, only the Stage itself, so I have a full screen background, with a 400x300 Pane (With its tiny Buttons) on the top-left corner of my screen.

TL;DR: The example code the buttons stay in the top-left corner of the screen, and the rest is just an empty space when I scale up resolution.

**Update 2;** Forgot the Java Code.

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("UI.fxml"));
Scene scene = new Scene(root, java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width,
            java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height);
stage = new Stage();
stage.setMaximized(false);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.setTitle("Example Menu");
stage.show();
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's impossible to help without seeing some code. Sounds like a layout problem, maybe hard-coded positions or sizes. Did you read the comments on the linked question? Seems to be a similar problem.

Comment: I hard coded nothing. I did everything with `JavaFX SceneBuilder 2`, and when looking at size, everything (Min, pref and max) says `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE`. I understand it is hard to help without seeing the code, but if I put the code online I might get fired, and I don't want that, sorry. Thank you for trying to help :)

Comment: I see, but maybe you can code a small, self-contained example that is not related to your work? Just a simple screen with one or two components to simulate the problem?

Comment: Your code and fxml would be nice to see :)

Comment: Added Java and FXML code of a little example I just did.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34487258/1288408 <- Take a look at this answer for a way to set preferred width and height in an fxml file based on screen resolution. Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set anchor pane constraints on child. in your case gridpane

```
AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0"
```

This will go after your

```
 GridPane prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="400.0" **HERE**
```

This will maximize Child component within container , hence  0 0 0 0 pixels from each side .

Comment: You can't even imagine how much I love you right now :) This worked perfectly for the little example.

Comment: I am guessing I need to add this code to every panel in the actual project to have all the elements be scaled, right? For example, if I have a button inside a GridPane, I would add GridPane.leftAnchor="0,0 "...and the rest to the Button element. Is that ok?

Comment: Well anchor pane works like anchor , when you put  children in there , its hardcoded poisition .If you maximize window  for instance on higher resolution then you prepared for , in yoru scenebuidler where it looked alright , it doesnt know anything else just that hardcoded position , so it looks wierd if you scale it it iwll just stay static at that pixel within parent.

Comment: I rarely use AnchorPane , thing is you use it for osmething its really not designed to , jsut use Borderpane , me myself im addicted to borderpanes , hboxes,vboxes . pick container that scales controls.

Comment: And yes , if you will use anchorpanes , you have to set this property to make sure your control scales , in scenebuilder click on children of Anchorpane you wanna scale , and in Layout option you have nice UI Anchor Pane Constraints. Set 0 to all sides or other value if needed